# How would I integrate and run all the functions that are stored in another folder in my index.js on my express app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, discord.js, twilio

So I'm rewriting my app for it to be cleaner and instead of 800 lines of code in my index.js, I moved all my functions to separate individual files in my "Text Functions" folder. The question I have is, now that I moved all my functions into separate files in the functions folder, how would I run them now in my index.js? The app monitors for new, incoming discord message embeds and sends you a text to your phone notifying you that you just got an embed. Originally, I had all the functions in my index.js to where it'll just go down the list of functions one by one, but now I'm wanting it to call that function that's stored in another folder in my index.js when a new discord message embed comes in. Below I attached my current index.js and one of the function files.

index.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 25;
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent, , GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers] });
const twilio = require('twilio')(process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);


const { sendCyberSuccess } = require("./Text Functions/personalSMS");



const express = require('express')
const app = express();
    app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));



app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 3000');
 });
 
 client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
```

personalSMS.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 25;
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent, , GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers] });
const twilio = require('twilio')(process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);



function sendCyberSuccess(sms) {
    twilio.messages.create({
        body: sms,
        to: process.env.PERSONAL_NUMBER,
        from: process.env.TWILIO_NUMBER,
    });
 }


client.on("messageCreate", function(message) {
    if (message.channel.id == cyberSuccessID && message.author.id != myUserId) {

        let author = message.author.username.toString()

        message.embeds.forEach((embed) => {
            let description = embed.description
            let title = embed.title.toString()


            if (author.includes('Cybersole') && title.includes("Successfully checked out!")) {
                let updatedAuthor = author.replace("Cybersole", 'Senpai Notifier')
                let updatedTitle = title.replace("Successfully checked out!", "Checked Out! ")
    
                const sms6 = `Status: ${updatedTitle}\n\nDescription: ${description}\n\nHey Brandon, it looks like you checked out something on Cybersole. Amazing job! Onto the next drop \n\nNotified By ${updatedAuthor}`;
                sendCyberSuccess(sms6);

            } else if (author.includes('Cybersole') && title.includes("Your card was declined!")) {
                let updatedAuthor = author.replace("Cybersole", 'Senpai Notifier')
                let updatedTitle = title.replace("Your card was declined!", "Declined ❌")

                const sms7 = `Status: ${updatedTitle}\n\nHey you just got a decline.That's not 4PF \n\nNotified By ${updatedAuthor}`
                sendCyberSuccess(sms7);
            }


        }
    )} 
})
```

Comment: Try to use `module.exports` to export the function in others file and then require it at wherever you need to use it. Hopefully I did not misunderstand your question

Comment: That I already know! but when I run my index.js, the functions themselves aren’t being ran so I was asking how would I write my index.js file to run said functions

Comment: I cannot see if you are calling these outputted modules in your index file. I think you should have a look on command handling